# GCP Pubsub batch publishing triggering 3 to 4x time messages than actual number of messages

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, fastify

I am trying to publish messages via google pubsub batch publishing feature. The batch publishing code looks like below.

```
const gRPC = require("grpc");
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

const createPublishEventsInBatch = (topic) => {
  const pubSub = new PubSub({ gRPC });
  const batchPublisher = pubSub.topic(topic, {
    batching: {
      maxMessages: 100,
      maxMilliseconds: 1000,
    },
  });

  return async (logTrace, eventData) => {
    console.log("Publishing batch events for", eventData);
    try {
      await batchPublisher.publish(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(eventData)));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error in publishing", err);
    }
  };
};
```

And this batch publisher is getting called from a service like this.

```
const publishEventsInBatch1 = publishEventFactory.createPublishEventsInBatch(
  "topicName1"
);
const publishEventsInBatch2 = publishEventFactory.createPublishEventsInBatch(
  "topicName2"
);

events.forEach((event) => {
  publishEventsInBatch1(logTrace, event);
  publishEventsInBatch2(logTrace, event);
});
```

I am using push subscription to receive the messages with the below settings.

```
Acknowledgement deadline: 600 Seconds
Retry policy: Retry immediately
```

The issue I am facing is, if the total number of events/messages is 250k, the push subscription is supposed to get less than or equal to 250k messages based on the message execution. But in my case, I am getting 3-4 M records on subscription and it is getting varied.

My fastify and pubsub configuration is

```
fastify: 3.10.1
@google-cloud/pubsub: 2.12.0
```

Adding the subscription code

```
fastify.post("/subscription", async (req, reply) => {
  const message = req.body.message;
  let event;
  let data;
  let entityType;
  try {
    let payload = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
    event = JSON.parse(payload);
    data = event.data;
    entityType = event.entityType;
    if (entityType === "EVENT") {
      if (event.version === "1.0") {
        console.log("Processing subscription");
        await processMessage(fastify, data);
      } else {
        console.error("Unknown version of stock event, being ignored");
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Ignore event");
    }
    reply.code(200).send();
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.status === 409) {
      console.error("Ignoring stock update due to 409: Conflict");
      reply.code(200).send();
    } else {
      console.error("Error while processing event from subscription");
      reply.code(500).send();
    }
  }
});
```

Can any one guide me where I am doing the mistakes. It's a simple fastify application. Do I am making any mistake in coding or any configuration.

Comment: Can you provide your subscriber code as well? Also, do the duplicates that you receive have the same message ID or do they have different message IDs?

Comment: How events is populated?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn , I have added the subscription code as well.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon

const createEvent = (data, entityType, eventType, traceHeaders, version) => {
  const uuid = uuidv1();
  const date = new Date();

  return {
    eventId: uuid,
    eventType,
    entityId: data.uuid,
    entityType,
    timestamp: date.getTime(),
    mimeType: "application/json",
    version,
    traceHeaders,
    data
  };
};
This is how we are generating the event.

Comment: I have tried these examples ([1](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-batch-settings#pubsub_publisher_batch_settings-nodejs), [2](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/main/samples/publishBatchedMessages.js)) from the documentation and they worked fine. Have you tried them? If not, I suggest you refer to them and try to adapt your code from there.

Comment: Also, if you tried one of those examples and you also reproduced the issue, this could mean the issue is on the side of fastify (hence, raising an issue on their [repo](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) would be the next step).